# How to refresh partial view by another partial view without scripting?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to refresh partial view by another partial view. My structure would be

I want to update 3rd partial view on the submit of first partial view

I am rendering first partial from main Index view by using

```
@{Html.RenderAction("SearchMenu", "Search");}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use ajax for it, I don't think there is any other possible solution for it, you can check out this answer: [How to update partial view from another partial view via action results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36865722/how-to-update-partial-view-from-another-partial-view-via-action-results)
 I hope it'll work for you